# How can I fix my CSS/HTML that uses input:checked, to prevent radio button movement?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I used an example CSS + HTML code to create a series of "page covers" that are selectable as re-designed radio buttons.  Everything is working great, except when I click on some of the "covers", the row below it keeps moving instead of being stationary.  How can I fix this to stop the covers from moving?  Please see the example.

**Running Example**

Be sure to run it using `Full Page` option.

- Click on "cover" 1, 2, 3, etc.
- Observe the shifting row below the cover you click - it shifts and arranges itself to be after the clicked cover
- Expected behavior:  None of the covers are to move places, no matter which cover you click.

**Snippet**

```css
.center {
  text-align: center
}
.cover_width {
  width: 200px
}
label>input+img {
  /* IMAGE STYLES */
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}
label>input:checked+img {
  /* (CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px green;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div style="text-align:left">
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>



  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change border size and margins when `checked`

```css
.center {
  text-align: center
}
.cover_width {
  width: 200px
}
label>input+img {
  /* IMAGE STYLES */
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
label>input:checked+img {
  /* (CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px green;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div style="text-align:left">
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>
    <label style="float:left" class='cover_width center'>
      <input type="radio" name="coverpage" value="coverpage" style="display:none;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYzw.png">
      <br>Original Cover</label>



  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I am temped to say "How did you do that!?", because this is magic and I wouldn't have known to look for that.

Comment: @Dennis If you had, I would have said "abra kadabra .. zaazaam" while waving my magic stick ... :)

Comment: I did say it outloud!

Comment: @Dennis Those are the same mistakes I made in the beginning ... almost wripping all my hair off after 48 hours not seeing why stuff like that happened ... have hair left though slightly more gray today :)